# Alterando cor do titulo da minha aplicação

Tags: android, android-layout

Já tentei variooooos códigos para alterar a cor do titulo que fica na actionbar da aplicação, mas nada, creio que seja simples, mas não to conseguindo saber como. uso o "Theme.AppCompat.Light", tema criado pelo Action Bar Style Generator.

[image: print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido :)

```
<style name="MeuAppActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MeuAppActionBar</item>                
    </style>

    <style name="MeuAppActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MeuApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MeuApp.SubTitleTextStyle</item>               
        <item name="background">@color/azul_escuro</item>                
    </style>

    <style name="MeuApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/branco</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="MeuApp.SubTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/branco</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>
```